# PHP Como eu faço para multiplicar horas com a quantidades de vezes que vai ser repetido?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela em meu **MySQL** de produtos com tempo, exemplo:

**Tabela Processos**

> id - descrisão - Tempo
>
> 01 - Furar - 0:01:50

Exemplo se eu mandar fabricar uma peça que tem 5 furos, eu tenho que multiplicar quantidade pelo tempo.

```
echo $tempo * 5;
```

a variável `$tempo`, é pego na tabela processos.

Mas me retorna **0**, ao invés de retornar **0:09:10**
O que está errado ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer de duas maneiras a mesma solução.

1. Diretamente no MySQL utilizando funções de conversão [TIME_TO_SEC](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time_to_sec-function.php) e [SEC_TO_TIME](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-sec_to_time-function.php)

   ```
   SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
            TIME_TO_SEC('00:01:50') * 5
          ) as TEMPO_TOTAL
   ```
2. Fazendo no PHP

   ```
   $tempo = "00:01:50"; // Formato: 'HH24:MI:SS'
   $furos = 5;

   $str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $tempo);
   sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

   // tempo total em segundos
   $tempo_total = ($hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds) * $furos; 

   echo gmdate("H:i:s", $tempo_total); //Formata o tempo total para visualização
   ```

Comment: Obrigado Everson , no mysql não da para meu processo, pois uma peça tem 5 furos, outra tem nenhuma, outra tem mais de 1000 furos.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$hora = "04:15:57";

//Transformar em segundos
$tmp = explode(':', $hora);
$segundos = $tmp[0] * 3600 + $tmp[1] * 60 + $tmp[2];

//Aplica a multiplicação
$segundos = $segundos * 5;

//Tranformar em hora
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $segundos);

?>
```